# Does Burzynski have a miracle cancer cure being suppressed by the FDA?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, cancer, fda

I received [this Mercola announcement](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2011/06/11/burzynski-the-movie.aspx)  for the movie, [Burzynski](http://www.burzynskimovie.com/) about [Stanislaw Burzynski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanislaw_Burzynski)'s (allegedly) amazing cure for cancer, which uses *[antineoplastons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antineoplaston)*.

The Mercola article claims some fairly hefty things, such as:

> Burzynski, the Movie is the story of a medical doctor and Ph.D biochemist named Dr. Stanislaw Burzynski who won the largest, and possibly the most convoluted and intriguing legal battle against the Food and Drug Administration in American history.

and

> You will learn that not only did the US Federal government spend 14 years actively suppressing a cancer treatment that had a FAR greater success rate than any other treatment available, they also spent well over $60 million of US taxpayer dollars trying to put the inventor of the treatment in jail in order to steal his patents and either suppress or cash in on his discovery.

But [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanislaw_Burzynski) says:

> Burzynski had appealed the limitations on his advertising [due to a cease and desist order from the FDA] on the grounds of free speech, but the appeal court upheld the decision, stating that "Burzynski's commercial speech does not concern a lawful activity."
>
> ...The 2010 film Burzynski directed by Eric Merola, documents Burzynski's **efforts** to gain FDA approval for the therapy. [emphasis mine]

**My resultant questions are:**

- Is there any evidence for his "cure"? In order for the FDA to suppress a cure that had a "FAR greater success rate than any other treatment available," well, it has to be shown to be successful at all.
- Is Mercola correct in reporting that Burzynski *won* the most important battle against the FDA in American history? Wikipedia seems to indicate that the FDA ruling still stands.

---

I suspect that the new, shiny developments in this industry that one doesn't hear about until Mercola advertises it were probably never much to begin with. Also, they unsurprisingly tend to involve aspects of a "big government conspiracy," and the bundled accusation that the only thing the US government cares about is keeping its citizens diseased and broke.

Nevertheless, I'm still interested in facts others can find, as well as making this a reference for other googlers. I will say that he has quite the [list of publications](http://www.burzynskiclinic.com/publications.html), but it's difficult to find reviews of Burzynski's work that *aren't* published by him.

Comment: Doesn't this count as spam?

Comment: @DJClayworth: Haha! Kind of... I signed up quite a while ago when I was, erm, perhaps less skeptical. Most of the time I delete without opening, but occasionally, there's something I'm interested in looking into a bit further to stay up-to-date on current "woo."

Comment: I came across this question after reading [this story about legal threats from the Burzynski Clinic](http://www.quackometer.net/blog/2011/11/the-burzynski-clinic-threatens-17-year-old-blogger.html) made against numerous skeptics sites, including a 17 year old blogger. If it looks like a duck, and sounds like a duck, it probably *is* a "quack"! :)

Comment: Given the kind of pseudoscientifc nonsense you can get away with selling over the counter in America as "alternative medicine" I don't think a lack of FDA approval would be a real obstacle to anybody.

Comment: I will note that most "supplements" sold in the US bear this statement:  **These statements have not been evaluated by the Food and Drug Administration.  This product is not intended to diagnose, treat, cure or prevent any disease.**  IOW, what you can claim a drug/supplement does is somewhat restricted, but this doesn't significantly restrict selling the item, so long as it's not toxic.  (BTW, the above is copied from a jar of ribose pills, commonly used to treat MADD/AMP deaminase deficiency, a real disease.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From 2008:  http://www.cancer.gov/cancertopics/pdq/cam/antineoplastons/patient/page1

My government firewall strips all formatting, so I can't do what is required to make this answer look pretty, but the basic gist is (again, suggest you go to the Cancer.gov site for the links, and emphasis mine):

> Antineoplastons are chemical compounds that are found normally in urine and blood. For use in medical research, antineoplastons can be made from chemicals in a laboratory. (See Question 1.)
>
> Antineoplaston therapy was developed by Dr. S. R. Burzynski, who proposed the use of antineoplastons as a possible cancer treatment in 1976. (See Question 2.)
>
> **No randomized, controlled trials showing the effectiveness of antineoplastons have been published in peer-reviewed scientific journals.** (See Question 6.)
>
> Nonrandomized clinical trials are ongoing at Dr. Burzynski’s clinic to study the effect of antineoplastons on cancer. (See Question 6.)
>
> Antineoplastons have caused mild side effects and some serious nervous system problems. (See Question 7.)
>
> Antineoplastons are not approved by the U. S. Food and Drug Administration for the prevention or treatment of any disease. (See Question 8.)

**EDIT TO ADD:**  You have to ask, if this is a cure, and the FDA is supressing it, why isn't it being used in areas that the FDA has no authority?  Things that make you go "Hmm?"

---

**Edit from Asker:** This was a great answer! I'm simply adding links to two more resources I found on my own to add to it for anyone else who stumbles across this (hope the answerer does not mind!).

- [HERE](http://www.houstonpress.com/2009-01-01/news/cancer-doctor-stanislaw-burzynski-sees-himself-as-a-crusading-researcher-not-a-quack/) is quite a long writeup/interview with Burzynski by the Houston Press.

> In 1998, Paul Goldberg, editor of The Cancer Letter, a D.C.-based newsletter covering cancer research and drug approval, investigated Burzynski's claims up to that point. He asked three renowned and independent researchers to examine Burzynski's scientific protocols — all three said they could not make sense of the data, saying it did not resemble any commonly accepted models. Ten years later, Goldberg and two of those doctors don't feel any differently.
>
> Henry Friedman, a neuro-oncologist at the Duke University Medical Center, was one of the independent doctors who reviewed the data for Goldberg. [He said,] "Despite thousands of patients treated with the antineoplastons, no one has yet shown in a convincing fashion, [through] the rigorous requirements for peer review, that the therapy works"...

- [HERE](http://www.quackwatch.org/01QuackeryRelatedTopics/Cancer/burzynski1.html) is a summary about Burzynski from QuackWatch.

> Burzynski has never demonstrated that A-2.1 (PA) or "soluble A-10" (PA and PAG) are effective against cancer or that tumor cells from patients treated with these antineoplastons have been "normalized." Tests of antineoplastons at the National Cancer Institute have never been positive. The drug company Sigma-Tau Pharmaceuticals could not duplicate Burzynski's claims for AS-2.1 and A-10. The Japanese National Cancer Institute has reported that antineoplastons did not work in their studies. No Burzynski coauthors have endorsed his use of antineoplastons in cancer patients.

Comment: Your firewall strips all formatting?  Jesus.

Comment: When I was in the AF, we called IT "preventers of Information".  It's sad!  I worked in a weapons research office, and they blocked a website because of "Category: Weapons"...  I kid you not.  It's draconian!

Comment: nice answer! For dessert, could you edit and add links to [THIS](http://www.houstonpress.com/2009-01-01/news/cancer-doctor-stanislaw-burzynski-sees-himself-as-a-crusading-researcher-not-a-quack/) writeup about him from the Houston Press and [THIS](http://www.quackwatch.org/01QuackeryRelatedTopics/Cancer/burzynski1.html) article I found from QuackWatch? I think they'll supplement the answer nicely.

Comment: @Larian - well, if they don't, and some wacko decides to come to the workplace and shoot people, it's some bureaucrat's job. Of course, I'd be EXTREMELY surprised if they blocked, say AQAP's website - that'd be evil profiling :(

Answer (score 7):

I concur with the [answer from Brightblades](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4611/does-burzynski-have-a-miracle-cancer-cure-being-suppressed-by-the-fda/4614#4614), which addresses the lack of clinical evidence.

That leaves the question about the legal situation.

From the Wikipedia page references, I found a [decision for case NO. 03-95-00222-CV](http://www.3rdcoa.courts.state.tx.us/opinions/HTMLopinion.asp?OpinionID=847) at the Texas Court of Appeals, in the case between Burzynski and the Texas State Board of Medical Examiners.

Its summary states:

> Appellant Texas State Board of Medical Examiners ("the Board") ordered that appellee Dr. Stanislaw Burzynski's license to practice medicine be suspended and that such suspension be stayed with Dr. Burzynski being placed on probation for ten years under certain conditions. (1) Upon judicial review of the Board's order, the district court reversed the order in its entirety and dismissed the cause. In two points of error, the Board asserts that the trial court erred in finding that TMPA section 5.09(a) authorizes Dr. Burzynski's use of antineoplastons in Texas and that the false advertising statute is unconstitutional. We will reverse the judgment of the trial court and render judgment in accordance with the order of the Board.

To summarise the summary:

- The Board suspended his license.
- The District Court reviewed and reversed the suspension.
- The Texas Court of Appeals reversed the reversal, leaving his license suspended again.

This confusing back-and-forth explains why the difference sources appear to be contradicting each other.

Comment: And I don't believe putting someone in jail enables the government to "steal their patent", but I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: There is - as far as I know - no law or regulation that says that any patents you may or may not own default to the government if you're ever jailed any more than that any other belongings get instantly confiscated, but that should be easy enough to check. Ask a lawyer.

Comment: @Shadur, that is easy... You pay for it! :-)

Comment: @Odd - the government can "steal" any patent they want. Patents are **not** secret. They are there to prevent someone from using the invention without paying the patent holder.

Comment: @DVK, I agree with your 2nd and 3rd sentence, but that raises the question of what "stealing" means in the 1st. Surely "stealing" a patent can only mean retracting or reassigning the exclusive rights granted with a patent. I don't believe being convicted would limit a patent owners right's in any way, especially as the jail time may be short in comparison to the patent length. But I have no reference to support that position.

Comment: @Odd - While technically you can call that stealing, I was thinking more in the line of reassigning rights to itself. However, in light of #2/3, #1 is rather irrelevant

Comment: For protection of the state and certain economical industries, such as energy, the US government may seal a patent under the [Invention Secrecy Act.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invention_Secrecy_Act) That's not related to imprisonment as far as I know, and also the act requires that you are fairly compensated for the patent, but never allowed to develop products utilizing it (or even talk about it under threat of imprisonment). So that's not really stealing, but I thought you might like to know that patents can and have been taken by the US government.

Comment: On retrospect, also telling (but not definite by the rules of skepticism here) is that the great legal victory he claims to have won in the movie (and which got reversed later on) was that the court ruled that *false advertising was protected speech*, not that his advertising wasn't false. Which reminds me of the xkcd statement about when the best argument you have is that it's not literally illegal to say what you did, you don't have much of an argument.

Answer (score 2):

I was about to make a post on the same subject and found plenty of information here, so decided to append to the archive ... here are some [clinical trial data](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=antineoplastons&no_unk=Y&pg=1) on his work ...

If you exclude the enormous amount of studies with an unknown status, you ignore the withdrawn and terminated studies, there's only one completed study; which doesn't actually have a completion date listed, nothing published and the only investigators are listed as `Stanislaw R. Burzynski, MD, PhD` and `Burzynski Research Institute`  .

[image]

Comment: More details about the "Completed" study are here: https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT00003509. It had 13 participants and ran from 1996 to 2005.